# Counting records of all files in the directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

So the scenario is as follows:
I receive a bunch of files everyday and I want to count the number of records in each file(excluding headers) of the directory and display in a CSV file the counts along with the file names.

I'm using the following command but am unable to write in csv format. I know I'm close to the solution. But just not close enough. Please help.

```
find . -type f \( -name "${FILE_NAME}" \) | xargs wc -l | aaj -F "," '{print $1-1, "\011",$2}' >> count.csv
```

FILE_NAME is the variable in which i am storing the format of the filenames (=XYZ*{DATE}*.dat)

My major challenge is with the CSV format as I want to email that file so that the user can open it in MS Excel. I am able to output a tab delimited text file. But I would prefer a CSV.

Comment: just specify `OFS=','` for your **"aaj"** tool...

Comment: What is that `"\011"`? Och, it's a tab. Just `\t`. So if you know how to output a tab, why not just `","` output a comma there?

Comment: You are already counting the records of the cvs files, excluding headers. if you separate the lines with comma, it is cvs output also. I don't see you are "not close enough", you are already there.

Comment: Simplest solution I could think of should be `find -type f \( -name "${FILE_NAME}" \) -exec awk 'FNR>1{count++} END{print count}' {} \+` try it out if this helps you. I am not sure why you need to mention field separator when you need to just count the total number of lines, let us know how it goes(Please make sure shell variable `FILE_NAME` is set with value before you run this command).